# Откуда берется это белое пространство когда экран уменьшаешь?

Tags: html, css, отладка

Когда навожу на элемент, ничего не показывает. Что это может быть ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Даниил Спасибо за догадку (подсказку)я исходя твоего ответа подумал и чекнул  Я там намутил трешак с одной секция которая вылазит Спасибо !

Comment: @Air, да тут вроде и без кода ясно... А код разбирать за автора всё равно желания нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy с одной стороны да, с другой если ему нужно конкретное решение данного вопроса с этого ресурса, необходимо добавить код или ссылку. Тогда автору вопроса уже и дадут точный ответ решения данной проблемы. Но придется покапатся в коде, да.

Comment: @Qwertiy не только может, но и должен делать это самостоятельно :)) В данном случае у автора наверное не много опыта в верстке, и ему нужен был некий толчок или наставление, зачем он и пришел сюда.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72832/discussion-on-question-by-lolik231-------).

Answer (score 2):

У тебя один из элементов по ширине больше, чем окно.

В devtools удаляй вложенные в `body` элементы по одному до тех пор, пока ширина не изменится. Когда это произойдёт, нажми <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> чтобы отменить последнее удаление. Разверни проблемный элемент и продолжи удалять из него. И так до тех пор, пока не найдёшь элемент, который вылезает за пределы родителя.

Довольно частая причина - подобные стили:

```
width: 100%;
padding: 0 15px;
box-sizing: content-box; /* по умолчанию в браузере */
```

или

```
width: 100%;
margin: 0 15px;
```

а также использование фиксированной ширины.

Если это пространство появляется только при уменьшении ширины экрана, то дело в фиксированном значении `width` или `min-width` (ну если исключить переход на другой media-запрос, в котором и допущен косяк из первого списка).